# Как достать html код страницы из webView Android?

Tags: java, android, webview

Добрый день. 
Нужно вытащить из WebView Android ссылку на одно изображение. Как можно достучаться до html из java кода?

Answer (score 4):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32040564/3212712), с API 19 можно так:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(
    "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
     new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
            Log.d("HTML", html); 
            // code here
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны первое парсить и найти ссылку до изображения.
[пример парсинга сайта](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/jsoup.php)
Или же напрямую указать ссылку изображения.
[Здесь пример изпользования](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageview.php)