# Android. Отправить POST запрос в iframe в webview

Tags: android, post, iframe, android-webview

Нужно в андроид отправить POST запрос с параметрами в hidden iframe в webview, такое требование бэка, в вебе работает, надо под андроид запилить.
Само webview есть, postUrl() не прокатил. Урл динамический типа "https://mysite.ru/server/api/v1/client/gather?TransID=1234567879"
Как? И можно ли?
Гугл ничего мне за день поисков не выдал или я не так спрашиваю и вообще слабо понимаю что от меня хотят.

Comment: Это крайне редкая задача, потому и информации мало. Вам надо 2 задачи решить. 1. Найти пример отправки POST запроса на JS. 2. Выполнить код из п1. в WebView. Это можно примерно так сделать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758171/17609

Answer (score 2):

ЮрийСПб показал правильное направление. В итоге такой код заработал:

```
val jsString = "fetch('%s', {\n" +
"    method: 'POST',\n" +
"    mode: 'no-cors',\n" +
"    headers: {\n" +
"        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'\n" +
"    },\n" +
"});"
val script = String.format(jsString, "https://mysite.ru/server/api/v1/client/gather?TransID=1234567879")
webview.evaluateJavascript(script) {res ->
Log.d(TAG, res)
}
```